# react native custom snippets doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I recently found out about the custom snippets function of visual code and for me I think this can save me a lot of time for coding and when starting over a new project. For me to be able to use it's full potential, I tried first with a simple snippet and will add more if I the current basic one is working.

Now my problem is that I have created a custom snippet for creating a class component.

I've tried saving it and typing in the prefix but it just won't work. 
I am using windows 10 and I navigated through the custom snippets by pressing file> preferences >user snippets> javascriptreact.json I also tried it in typescriptreact.json

What is the problem with this? Can somebody help me. Thank you very much!

```
{
    "Class Component for Navigators": {

        "prefix": "ccn",
        "body": [
            "class ${1} extends Component",
            "{",
            "\trender(){",
            "\t\treturn (",
            ");",
            "}",
            "}",    
        ],
        "description": "class component for navigators",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your snippet and it does work.

However I put the snippet in `javascript.json` instead of `javascriptreact.json`

Try putting it there and see if it works.

Comment: thank you very much it worked! Did not even try that because im not writing javascript. Now I can work on creating more custom snippets. Thanks again, Andrew.